# Cloning from master/main or cloning from fork?

Tags: git, github

I am new to git/GitHub and am trying to understand and emulate the typical workflow and have run into conflicting advice.

The guidelines for the [FirstContributions](https://github.com/firstcontributions/first-contributions) repository suggest that the typical workflow should be:

> fork -> clone -> edit -> pull request

However, the guidelines for the another [repository](https://github.com/asmeurer/git-workflow) for beginners state the following:

> Always clone from the main repository and add your fork as a remote.

Please help me understand the merits of each approach. Which one should I be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you will want to have the original repository available as a remote on your local repository. Whether you clone from the main repository and then add your fork as a remote or do it the other way around doesn't really matter.

The reason you want the original repository available is so that when you make changes in the future, you can base them on the current state of the remote repository, rather than on the state of the remote repository at the time you created your fork.

If you use the official `gh` CLI (available from https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/), this is as simple as:

- `git clone <original repository url>`
- `cd working_directory`
- `gh repo fork --remote`

This will (a) fork the repository on github, and then (b) configure
two remotes in your local directory:

- `origin` points to your fork, and
- `upstream` points to the original repository

When you start working on a new pull request, first update the state of the upstream repository:

```
git remote update upstream
```

And then create a new branch based on the main upstream branch:

```
git switch -c my_feature upstream/main
```

(The upstream main branch may be named `main` or `master` or `trunk`, so your command might look slightly different).